# colorbox not loading in <head>

Tags: functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-head

I can not get colorbox fully loaded.

I am trying to add color box to use in my plugin admin.

I do not need it for the front end.

I can get the css but can not get jquery.colorbox-min.js or the inline script to load in the `<head>`.

Here is what I have:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*    admin Stylesheet
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_wlmm_admin_stylesheets' );

function add_wlmm_admin_stylesheets() {
    if (is_admin()) {

        /*
         * Includes css for:
         *
         *  - plugin optins framework
         *  - colorbox
        */
      wp_enqueue_style( 'wlmm-admin-style', WLMM_URL . 'admin/css/wlmm-admin-styles.css' );
  }
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      load colorbox for admin help images
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wlmm_do_colorbox_js' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wlmm_do_colorbox_script' );

function wlmm_do_colorbox_js() {

    if (is_admin()) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'colorbox', WLMM_URL . 'admin/scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  }
}

function wlmm_do_colorbox_script() {

if ( ! defined( 'COLORBOX_WIDTH' ) ) define( 'COLORBOX_WIDTH', '95' );
if ( ! defined( 'COLORBOX_HEIGHT' ) ) define( 'COLORBOX_HEIGHT', '95' );
if ( ! defined( 'COLORBOX_OPACITY' ) ) define( 'COLORBOX_OPACITY', '0.6' );

// Colorbox settings
echo '
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("a.admin").colorbox({ width:'.COLORBOX_WIDTH.', height:'.COLORBOX_HEIGHT.', opacity:'.COLORBOX_OPACITY.' });
  });
</script>
';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the admin side, the two actions you want are [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) and [`admin_head-(plugin_page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-%28plugin_page%29).

`wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_head` are only for the front end.

Comment: Got it working...but only as admin-head and not admin_head-admin.php would not work but admin_head works fine. The admin page is admin.php?page=admin_plugin_options. I should have caught the admin_enqueue but the amin_head-plugin_page was new. So it's working but I would rather have it only load for admin.php.......thanks for the help.